# MS Access SQL Query - Find duplicate records

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have one table in MS Access called Customers. In that customers table, I have the following columns:

- CustomerID
- IdentificationID
- Address
  etc...

I want to write a query that will show me customerIDs that have a duplicate IdentificationID. Basically, show me customers that have the same IdentificationID.

I have written two queries but it either shows me the customerID only or the IdentificationID only. I would like it to show the CustomerID first and then the IdentificationID grouped by IdentificationID

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this should do it for you:

```sql
    SELECT CustomerID, IdentificationID
    FROM Customers
    GROUP BY CustomerID, IdentificationID 
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 2):

It also turns out that MS Access has an automated query wizard that search duplicates for you. Just go into Queries > Duplicate Records Query.

Comment: I don't know about 2013 because I do not have it but in 2010 this query will only work for 10 or fewer columns, if you have more than 10 columns you will then have to write a query such as that provided by otheres, but good reference to a ready made query.

Answer (score 0):

// haven't tested in MS Access, you can see the logic

```
SELECT *
    FROM Customers C
    WHERE EXISTS
    (
        SELECT 1
        FROM 
        (
            SELECT IdentificationID, COUNT(1) CNT
            FROM Customers
            GROUP BY IdentificationID
            HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
        ) I
        WHERE I.IdentificationID = C.IdentificationID
    )
    ;
```